# Possible number of Arrangement of given word with following conditions:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

- so that no two vowel come together.
- Repetition of letter is allowed.

For example:

Example 1 : "abe"
Answer : number of arrangements are 2. 
1)abe
2)eba

Example 2: "ae"
Answer : 0.
No possible arrangements.

Example 3: "abab"
Answer : 3
1)abab
2)baba
3)abba

I got stuck to generalize the formula for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What ideas do you have?

Comment: The idea is using negation.Example: "abe". Number of ways to arrange 3 letter word is 3!. Now number of ways so that vowel always come together is 2!. So,  number of arrangements possible is 2!*2!. (Considering ae as one letter and b as one letter). So total number of ways that vowels always come together is 4. Therefore Number of ways vowel never come together is : (Total number of ways) - (Number of ways vowel come together) i.e. 6 - 4 = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the so called *subtraction* method, use the *gap* method.

Suppose there are $5$ vowels and $8$ consonants

$- C - C - C - C - C - C - C - C -$

The $5$ vowels can go into any of the $9$ gaps, thus $\binom85$ placements.
If all the letters are distinct, $\binom955!8!$ permutations.
If, say, one vowel is repeated twice, and one consonant thrice, $\binom95\frac{5!8!}{2!3!}$ permutations.

You should now be in a position to derive a generalised formula.

*Happy New Year !*

Comment: What if number of vowels are more than the consonants. As in example 1 of the above question. Could you please help me out more in detail.

Comment: You should be able to realize that a solution is possible only for $V \le C+1.$ For example $1$, following the method suggested, answer is $\binom22 2!1! = 2$

Comment: You are welcome !